# Why can't I find the image added to my Android Solution sample?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mapsui

I'm still fairly new to Visual Studio/Xamarin. I'm trying to get an image into my Android sample.

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac community 8.4.5 (build 19) on macOS Mojava 10.14.6 and the following Packages:

- BruTile 2.1.2
- Mapsui 1.4.8
- OsmSharp 6.2.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 28.0.0.3
- Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 28.0.0.3
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 28.0.0.3
- Xamarin.Essentials 1.3.1

In my Solution I added an image to the following locations:

- Assets > Images > sample.png
- Resources > drawables > sample.png

Then I'm trying to find it using the following code:

```
    String target = "sample.png"
    Assembly resourceAssembly = null;
    String resourceName = null;
    Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Assembly: '" + assembly.GetName());
        try
        {
            String[] fileNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Name: '" + fileName + "'");
                if (fileName.ToUpper().EndsWith(target.ToUpper()))
                {
                    resourceAssembly = assembly;
                    resourceName = fileName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Not Supported for Assembly: '" + assembly.GetName() + "'  (" + e.GetType() + ")"
            );
        }
    }
    if (resourceName != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Resource file name [{0}] found as [{1}]", fileName, resourceName);
    }
```

The console log shows quite the number of assemblies and filenames, but never prints out the last line and thus does not find the sample.png file.

Why doesn't this code find the file? Did I add the file to the wrong location in my Solution? Or do I need to do something additionally?

(My current preference is to keep using the Assembly approach to find the file.)

Comment: ,According to your code, you want to use the above code to find the image. You want to get the image and to use? normally, I use `Resource.Drawable.sample` to get this image and to use, about Android Resource, please take a look [Android Resource Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-resource-basics?tabs=windows)

Comment: Apologies for my late response but thank you for yours. I've been trying to incorporate the following sample into my code: https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/1.4/Samples/Mapsui.Samples.Common/Maps/PointsSample.cs

However, I'd like to use my own image for the "pin". In this sample you see the usage of an Assembly to find the desired image, get a bitmap and use that. See the CreateBitmapStyle() and GetBitmapIdForEmbeddedResource(string imagePath) methods in that sample. But as mentioned, I'm having trouble getting to my custom image using this approach.

Comment: According to your sample, I guess that you want to get Embedded images from PCL? If yes, I think you can use ImageResourceExtension  to get this image:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do mate but if you are needing the image to show you can use the xaml.

```
<Image Source="sample.jpg" />
```

As long as the file name is all lower case, no special characters/numbers & is in - Resources > drawables it should show.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies for my late response but thank you for yours. I've been trying to incorporate the following sample into my code: https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/1.4/Samples/Mapsui.Samples.Common/Maps/PointsSample.cs

However, I'd like to use my own image for the "pin". In this sample you see the usage of an Assembly to find the desired image, get a bitmap and use that. See the CreateBitmapStyle() and GetBitmapIdForEmbeddedResource(string imagePath) methods in that sample.

But as mentioned, I'm having trouble getting to my custom image at all.